# Question about smoothing issues to the model

Tags: modeling, mesh

I imported a tank model from a game, extracted with Ninja Ripper. The model has some smoothing issues while even if I tried select the mesh and soft all verts, faces and edges in shading panel, the mesh still looks weird.

Also tried the auto smooth option. I'm not quite sure the faces are in this look due to only smoothing or also the flips or something inverted. With <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> I did found some of the faces on the turret turns different while some are not.

[image]

I don't know if it has something to do with flipped normals so I recalculated the normal with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and this is the output:

[image]

Comment: In Object Data > Geometry Data, try Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: Thx! But I checked the geometry data and the only one option can be used is Add Custom Split Normals Data.

Comment: so maybe share your file or at least a part of it? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks a lot! The file is here: https://pasteall.org/blend/dfa2cd18c9074d2791cfc060efe47df2

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 things to get a clean shading:

- You have sharp edges, so, in *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Clear Sharp*
- You have overlapping vertices, so, *Edit* mode, select all and (in 2.79) <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*
- As I said, in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Clear Custom Split Normals Data*

Comment: thank you so much! However ummm there's only a Add Custom Split Normals Data on my end in the panel. https://imgur.com/a4tUzEh

Comment: that's weird because I had the Clear button and I had to use it...

Comment: Can you help me to fix that? I tried reload a raw file but still Blender did not provide that option to me. Is it possible for you to fix and then send the the file in .obj to me? Thanks!

Comment: sure, here it is, tell me if it works: https://pasteall.org/blend/529e1517ccc34bb7aadfe3b3b859bdd8

Comment: Thank you so much! It is perfect! You saved my day!